# Can't add log with AspectJ on every method JDK6 and Spring 4.0.6.RELEASE

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop, aspect

I have an old application, which use java 6 and Spring 4.0.6.

I have a lot of problem adding log with log4j, the log are never ... logged.
So I only use System.out.println in the code, and it works great, all log are redirected in the server.log file.

I wanted to automatically add some log to trace every call of every method.
So I add this in my pom.xml :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

I create an Aspect class :

```
package com.al6.business.log;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.StopWatch;

@Component
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());
    
    @Around("execution(* com.al6.business.commande.CommandeBusiness.*(..))")
    public void logAroundAllMethods(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable 
    {
        log.info("Test with logger");
        System.out.println("****LoggingAspect.logAroundAllMethods() : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + ": Before Method Execution");
        try {
            joinPoint.proceed();
        } finally {
            //Do Something useful, If you have
        }
        System.out.println("****LoggingAspect.logAroundAllMethods() : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + ": After Method Execution");
    }


}
```

And in my xml beans file I add :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd">

  <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
  
 
  <bean id="tracerInvocation" class="com.al6.business.log.MyAspect">
  
  </bean>

...


</beans>
```

And here is an example of the code I need to monitor :

```
package com.al6.business.commande;

import ...
import org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Subqueries;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;


    /**
     * Manages order business service
     *
     */
    public class CommandeBusiness extends MainBusinessService implements ICommandeService, ITransfertService {
    
    
    @Override
    public void creerEnteteCommande(Commande commande, String idCommandeAPurger, Utilisateur utilisateur) {
        System.out.println("creerEnteteCommande " + commande.getId() + " par " + utilisateur + " Type doc : " + commande.getTypeDocument());
        ...
    }
...
}
```

In my server.log file, the Sysout in the method is logged correctly, but my aspect log is not here... :

```
2021-04-28 18:03:25,565 INFO  [STDOUT] creerEnteteCommande 81797581 par UTILISATEUR SUPER (admindsi) Type doc : CC
```

If I search for Aspect in server.log, I see :

```
2021-04-28 17:04:24,563 INFO  [STDOUT] 989  [ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-2] DEBUG org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory  - Found AspectJ method: public java.lang.Object com.al6.business.log.MyAspect.logAroundAllMethods(org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint) throws java.lang.Throwable
```

So why my logs are not here ?
I have a jboss-log4j.xml file on the server, is the configuration can make the aspectJ log inefficient ?

Thanks

Comment: Firstly, your pointcut says `com.al6.business.commande.CommandeBusiness.*(..)`, which does not fit the package name `com.al6.borneIntranet.business.commande`. Secondly, after you have fixed that, please also make sure that `CommandeBusiness` is declared as a Spring component. Spring AOP can only intercept Spring components/beans. If you want to intercept non-Spring-managed classes, you need to use native Aspect. Please let me know if this helps, then I can write an answer which you can accept in order to close the question, or I close the question as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks. The name of the package is correct, I just change it for posting my question, to make it more « generic » but I forget to modify everywhere in my post ^^ Yes CommandBusiness is not a component. I have like 50 Java classes to watch and none of them is component, I introduce « component » with this aspect class only. 
If I add component annotation everywhere I assume is not a good solution, so when you say « use native aspect » what do you want to say ? 
Thank you

Comment: I wanted to say "native AspectJ", my smartphone's auto-correct erased the "J", sorry. Follow the Spring documentation links in the answer I linked this duplicate to for more information. Here are the relvant legacy 4.0.6 documentation links for [Spring AOP](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop) and [native AspectJ support in Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-using-aspectj).

Comment: Ok thank you, when I read the : https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-using-aspectj
It seems to need modifying the actual java classes to make it work.
So in my case, if I don't want to touch at the business java classes, it seems that I need this : https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-aj-ltw-first-example
Correct ?

Comment: You do not need to change the classes at all, how did you get that idea? AspectJ will weave the aspects into the bytecode when the classes are loaded. This is way more efficient than Spring AOP. You need no proxies and have many more options for modification. Spring AOP is just "AOP lite" in comparison. AspectJ is very mature and enterprise-ready, with or without Spring. Even the Spring manual recommends it if you need more than Spring AOP has to offer.

Comment: Ok, I almost success, I just have this error now : 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [org.jboss.mx.loading.UnifiedClassLoader3] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:org.springframework.instrument.jar

Comment: If you read the manual and configured the system according to the description, but still have a problem, please ask a new question, explain the situation and the error message in detail and also provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), either in the question or ideally as a link to a GitHub repository. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I just do it here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67325255/cant-add-javaagent-for-aspectj