# Can't add javaagent for AspectJ

Tags: java, spring, jboss, aspectj, spring-aop

I have an old Java6 Application, and I'm trying to add some automatic and global log for tracing every call in every method.
It runs on a JBoss 4.2.3.

I follow this example :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-aj-ltw-first-example

I have my profiling class :

```
package com.al6.borneIntranet.business.log;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.util.StopWatch;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;

@Aspect
public class ProfilingAspect {

    @Around("methodsToBeProfiled()")
    public Object profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        StopWatch sw = new StopWatch(getClass().getSimpleName());
        try {
            sw.start(pjp.getSignature().getName());
            return pjp.proceed();
        } finally {
            sw.stop();
            System.out.println(sw.prettyPrint());
        }
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(public * com.al6.borneIntranet..*.*(..))")
    public void methodsToBeProfiled(){}
}
```

I create a META-INF/aop.xml file :

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>

    <weaver>
        <!-- only weave classes in our application-specific packages -->
        <include within="com.al6.*"/>
    </weaver>

    <aspects>
        <!-- weave in just this aspect -->
        <aspect name="com.al6.borneIntranet.business.log.ProfilingAspect"/>
    </aspects>

</aspectj>
```

I add this line in my bean definitions xml :

```
<context:load-time-weaver/>
```

And I have this dependencies :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

It almost works, but I have this error at startup when I use the application :

```
2021-04-29 18:41:46,960 ERROR [STDERR] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.weaving.AspectJWeavingEnabler#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loadTimeWeaver': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [org.jboss.mx.loading.UnifiedClassLoader3] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:org.springframework.instrument.jar
```

I download the spring-instrument-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar file from maven repository, then I add the javaagent part in the run startup script :

```
/opt/jdk/bin/java -Dprogram.name=run.sh -javaagent:/opt/jboss/lib/org.springframework.instrument.jar -server -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=256M ...
```

But the error still appear, like I'm doing nothing.

Is there a way to not add this option at startup easily ?
Why even when I add it it is not used ?

EDIT :

I try to add the adspectj launch agent, didn't work either, same error, it looks like the option is not detected by the application :

```
/bin/sh /opt/jboss/bin/run.sh -c commandes -b 0.0.0.0 -Djboss.partition.name=jboss-commande-preprod1-partition 
admin    22263 47.6 76.7 4911056 4023536 pts/0 Sl   16:03   2:14 /opt/jdk/bin/java -Dprogram.name=run.sh -javaagent:/opt/jboss/lib/aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar -javaagent:/opt/jboss/lib/org.springframework.instrument.jar -server -Xms3500m -Xmx
3500m -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999 -Dc
om.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -XX:+UseG1GC -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n -Djava.net.prefer
IPv4Stack=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/jboss/lib/endorsed -classpath /opt/jboss/bin/run.jar:/opt/jdk/lib/tools.jar org.jboss.Main -c commandes -b 0.0.0.0 -Djboss.partition.name=jboss-commande-preprod1-partition
```

EDIT 2 :

Try few things :

- Using Jboss timeweaver :

  Error creating bean with name 'loadTimeWeaver': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.instrument.classloading.jboss.JBossLoadTimeWeaver]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize JBoss LoadTimeWeaver because the JBoss 6 API classes are not available

Of course, I'm on Jboss 4.3.2

- Adding "-verbose -showWeaveInfo -debug" in aop.xml :

The file is detected because I have this lines at startup :

```
2021-05-03 15:11:42,267 ERROR [STDERR] [UnifiedClassLoader3@341a736] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.8.9 built on Monday Mar 14, 2016 at 21:18:16 GMT
2021-05-03 15:11:43,253 ERROR [STDERR] [UnifiedClassLoader3@341a736] info register classloader org.jboss.mx.loading.UnifiedClassLoader3@341a736
2021-05-03 15:11:43,253 ERROR [STDERR] [UnifiedClassLoader3@341a736] info using configuration file:/opt/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/weldom_commandes/tmp/deploy/tmp6458410370486804467BorneIntranetServeurMetier.ear-contents/BorneIntranetServeurMetier.jar!/META-INF/aop.xml
2021-05-03 15:11:43,253 ERROR [STDERR] [UnifiedClassLoader3@341a736] info using configuration file:/opt/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/weldom_commandes/tmp/deploy/tmp6458410370486804467BorneIntranetServeurMetier.ear-contents/spring-aspects-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/aop.xml
2021-05-03 15:11:43,259 ERROR [STDERR] [UnifiedClassLoader3@341a736] info register aspect com.al6.borneIntranet.business.log.ProfilingAspect
2021-05-03 15:11:43,474 ERROR [STDERR] [UnifiedClassLoader3@341a736] info register aspect org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect
2021-05-03 15:11:43,520 ERROR [STDERR] [UnifiedClassLoader3@341a736] info register aspect org.springframework.scheduling.aspectj.AnnotationAsyncExecutionAspect
2021-05-03 15:11:43,536 ERROR [STDERR] [UnifiedClassLoader3@341a736] info register aspect org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect
2021-05-03 15:11:43,544 ERROR [STDERR] [UnifiedClassLoader3@341a736] info register aspect org.springframework.cache.aspectj.AnnotationCacheAspect
2021-05-03 15:11:43,559 ERROR [STDERR] [UnifiedClassLoader3@341a736] debug not weaving 'com.al6.borneIntranet.business.ServiceArchiveEntryPointBean'
...
```

- When I put :

  ```
  <context:load-time-weaver
            weaver-class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
  ```

I have a slightly different error, but same result :

```
2021-05-03 15:15:03,475 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation.
2021-05-03 15:15:03,476 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver.addTransformer(InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver.java:88)
```

But I already add it :

```
-javaagent:/opt/jboss/lib/org.springframework.instrument.jar

ls -lrt /opt/jboss/lib : 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 admin users 7244 2021-04-30 16:03 /opt/jboss/lib/org.springframework.instrument.jar*
```

Comment: I updated my answer with some more info. See if it helps you make progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't find why load-time weaving don't work.

So, somebody at my work just ask me why I want to do loadtime weaving, why don't just do "compile time weaving".

I just add this in my pom.xml :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <complianceLevel>1.6</complianceLevel>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
        <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
        <encoding>UTF-8 </encoding>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <!-- use this goal to weave all your main classes -->
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I delete javaagent things.

Build, run, and tada, it's working.

I can't understand why almost nobody talk about this method, which does not require adding anything in startup arguments, anything complex, and it works much much easier.

Is there a big inconvenient at this ?
In fact, I wonder if it's not even better, because it weave classes at compile time, so it will be using less system ressource ?

Comment: That is a workaround rather than a solution for your problem. If lLTW is not working, usually the problem sits in front of the keyboard. With the requested MCVE I could have helped you. Please understand that adding any Java agent (not just AspectJ) to a container like and application server which uses multiple classloaders, trying to provide isolation for different applications, is inherently complex. I do agree that whenever compile-time weaving is a viable alternative, usually it is simpler.

Comment: By way of answering your question about system ressources: The resulting byte code is the same, no matter if you use LTW or CTW. The only difference is start-up time, which is faster with CTW, because using LTW means you have to do the weaving during class-loading instead of during compile time. Only in that case you cannot decide to deactivate the agent or a single aspect dynamically. If that is not a problem, CTW is the way to go. Only if you need more flexibility or have no access to the target code during compile time, you want to use LTW. Both have their merits.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Spring user, but when answering AspectJ LTW questions here I often noticed a certain discrepancy between the Spring documentation mentioning the need for the Spring Instrument Java agent only and the real situation in which there are ways to configure Spring like that, but it is tricky. The simplest approach by far is to also add the AspectJ Weaver agent to the command line, i.e. to use something like (on a single line, of course)

```
# AspectJ LTW
-javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar
# Spring Instrument
-javaagent:/path/to/org.springframework.instrument.jar
```

Maybe the AspectJ Weaver is enough already, it depends on your use case.

---

**Update** after the OP updated his question:

- Do you see any sign of the AspectJ weaver being loaded in your application server log? Scan for strings like `AspectJ Weaver Version`, `register classloader` or `using configuration .../aop.xml`. If you correctly added `aspectjweaver.jar` and `META-INF/aop.xml` to the project, you should see something like that, even if for some reason the aspect does not get triggered.
- Make sure that `META-INF/aop.xml` is found by the Java process. It is located via `Classloader.getResource()` by AspectJ. So whatever location or JAR you put it in, make sure that location is on the classpath. Experimentally, you could add a local directory to the classpath and see if the JVM finds the XML file there. Then, you can start to refine your approach if it is found this way.
- BTW, I see `<include within="com.al6.*"/>` which would only match classes directly in package `com.al6`. If you want to include subpackages, you need to use the `..` syntax, i.e. `<include within="com.al6..*"/>`.
- Furthermore, you linked to a how-to in the latest Spring manual with regard to native AspectJ + LTW configuration. You should rather use the [Spring 4.0.6 documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-using-aspectj), because you use that legacy version. I already sent you a link in my comment under [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67307965/1082681).

Please, first try to get the strings I mentioned in the first bullet point displayed by adding `-javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar`, before you try anything else. Only then, you might want to optimise or fine-tune:

For JBoss there is a special `JBossLoadTimeWeaver`. It should be auto-detected, but you could also specify it manually, see [this table of default weavers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-aj-ltw-spring-env-impls).

Comment: Thx, but weird, it change nothing.
The module I modify generate and EAR, and it's deployed in : 
/opt/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/commandes/deploy/BorneIntranetServeurMetier.ear

Comment: I update the original post with the complete launch command

Comment: Your launch command starts a shell script. Maybe you want to check if that script forwards the parameters as you expect it to. If not, just modify the script in order to make sure that the parameters arrive on the Java command line.

Comment: All the options like Xmx, Xms are ok and works, the script run.sh is a jboss native script, it takes the java_opts which are well defined.
Is there any other way to proceed which not require adding this option at startup ?
thx

Comment: You mean, you edited your question. So now we know that the AspectJ weaving agent is detected and started correctly. You did not really explain what else is not working as a consequence of the `Could not initialize JBoss LoadTimeWeaver because the JBoss 6 API classes are not available` error. The rest should be a configuration matter, not using the JBoss weaver but another one. But I cannot tell you more without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) project and brief setup instructions for your JBoss 4 server in order to reproduce your situation. I cannot fix what I cannot see.

Comment: Did you simply try with `-javagent:/my/aspectjweaver.jar` and without the fancy Spring configuration, just using stand-alone AspectJ in order to see if anything gets woven? That should work without Spring knowing about it, unless JBoss 4 has some classloader hierarchy conflicting with aspect weaving. [This old thread](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/aspectj-users/msg12912.html) shows that AspectJ and JBoss 4 are actually compatible. Let's just take Spring out of the equation for a moment for a while and focus on AspectJ.